# dc.js Adding a dynamic legend to a pie chart

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I am currently learning my way around dc.js which is amazing. I have been able to work most features and only thing at the moment I seem to be missing is a dynamic legend. I want to be able to click on legend and have chart redraw without the clicked object on the legend.

I have seen a few examples such as this one
http://www.datafootprints.com/loksabha/

If anyone can give me any pointers on how one can accomplish this I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The default behaviour is to include the element you click on, not exclude it (eg. when you click on the constituency in the example you gave).

On dc, legend is a specific type of graph, that I don't see having been used on the example you gave on datafootprints. Could you clarify what you meant by that?

Comment: I think @Rayzr8 is referring to the gender pie chart, where indeed clicking on the legend does filter. Is the question, how does this code work?